# Which ListBoxItem event should I use to implement a drag & drop and keep editable controls?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have developed a custom `CheckedListBox` that a user can use to specify which fields should be shown or not on a report. I now have a new requirement from the users to be able to reorder the fields in the order they would like to see them on the report. The way I'm trying to do it is to implement a drag & drop feature inside my `CheckedListBox`.

Currently, I'm using the `ListBoxItem.PreviewMouseMoveEvent` event to launch the drag. Combined with `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent` and `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUpEvent` to determine if the mouse is down during the move, and `DropEvent` to process the drop, everything works fine.

However, it seems that it prevents some event from firing, as it breaks the binding with the `IsChecked` property. I am in fact not able to check/uncheck an item anymore. The binding is done in `ListBox.ItemTemplate`, in which there's a simple `CheckBox` containing a `TextBlock` for the display text.

I tried using the `MouseMoveEvent`, which brings the `CheckBox` back to life but breaks the drag & drop feature. It seems that the `MouseMoveEvent` is not even fired anymore (that, or one of the mouse button event is not fired anymore).

The problem seems to be with this line: `DragDrop.DoDragDrop(draggedItem, draggedItem.DataContext, DragDropEffects.Move)`. If I remove it, I don't have a functional drag & drop, but all events are fired correctly.

Here's a sample of my code, at the experimentation stage:

```
    Public Sub New()

         ' This call is required by the designer.
         InitializeComponent()

         Items = New ObservableCollection(Of CheckListBoxItem)
         oListBox.ItemsSource = Items

         ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
         oListBox.ItemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(New Setter(ListBoxItem.AllowDropProperty, True))
         oListBox.ItemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(New EventSetter(ListBoxItem.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent, New MouseButtonEventHandler(AddressOf ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown)))
         oListBox.ItemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(New EventSetter(ListBoxItem.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUpEvent, New MouseButtonEventHandler(AddressOf ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp)))
         oListBox.ItemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(New EventSetter(ListBoxItem.PreviewMouseMoveEvent, New MouseEventHandler(AddressOf ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseMove)))
         oListBox.ItemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(New EventSetter(ListBoxItem.DropEvent, New DragEventHandler(AddressOf ListBoxItem_Drop)))

    End Sub

    Private source As CheckListBoxItem
    Private bMouseLeftButtonDown As Boolean = False

    Private Sub ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
        bMouseLeftButtonDown = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
         bMouseLeftButtonDown = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)

        If TypeOf sender Is ListBoxItem AndAlso bMouseLeftButtonDown Then
            Dim draggedItem As ListBoxItem = CType(sender, ListBoxItem)
            source = CType(draggedItem.DataContext, CheckListBoxItem)
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(draggedItem, draggedItem.DataContext, DragDropEffects.Move)
            draggedItem.IsSelected = True
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBoxItem_Drop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs)

        bMouseLeftButtonDown = False

        Dim target As CheckListBoxItem = CType((CType(sender, ListBoxItem)).DataContext, CheckListBoxItem)

        Dim removedIdx As Integer = Items.IndexOf(source)
        Dim targetIdx As Integer = Items.IndexOf(target)

        If (removedIdx < targetIdx) Then
            Items.Insert(targetIdx + 1, source)
            Items.RemoveAt(removedIdx)
        Else
            Dim remIdx As Integer = removedIdx + 1
            If (Items.Count + 1 > remIdx) Then
                Items.Insert(targetIdx, source)
                Items.RemoveAt(remIdx)
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
```

Here's a sample of my XAML:

```
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText}" />
                </CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

What I'm looking for is to find an event or a way to handle the events that will allow me to have a functional drag & drop as well as a functional `CheckBox`. I would accept an answer explaining a totally different approach, using a (free) third party library or not.

What I'm not looking for is code relying on a specific ViewModel, since this is intended to be a reusable control in our company, and not everything will be done MVVM-style. That's specifically the reason I created a `CheckListBoxItem` that acts as a "DataContext" for each list item.

Comment: Have you considered simple MoveUp/MoveDn buttons where you would basically just have to change the index of the selected checkbox?

Comment: I considered this option, but it's not really the most user-friendly.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the `ReorderListBox` control in the [WPF Bag Of Tricks](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot). It does exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came up with the solution of validating the `PreviewMouseMoveEvent` event by comparing the current position of the mouse minus the start position of the mouse (from the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent` event) with the minimum values to consider it a drag (`SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance` and `SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance`).

Here's a sample of the resulting code:

```
Private oSource As CheckListBoxItem
Private oStartPosition As Point

Private Sub ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
    oStartPosition = e.GetPosition(Nothing)
End Sub

Private Sub ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)

    If TypeOf sender Is ListBoxItem AndAlso e.LeftButton = MouseButtonState.Pressed Then

        Dim oCurrentPosition As Point = e.GetPosition(Nothing)

        If Math.Abs(oCurrentPosition.X - oStartPosition.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance OrElse Math.Abs(oCurrentPosition.Y - oStartPosition.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance Then

            Dim oDraggedItem As ListBoxItem = CType(sender, ListBoxItem)
            oSource = CType(oDraggedItem.DataContext, CheckListBoxItem)
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(oDraggedItem, oDraggedItem.DataContext, DragDropEffects.Move)
            oDraggedItem.IsSelected = True

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

It solves my problem because `DragDrop.DoDragDrop` is only called when the move is considered a drag, not when it's simply a selection of the item (check/uncheck the `CheckBox`).